# TigerVNC startup issues on Centos 7 instance running on GCP

Tags: centos-7, google-cloud-platform, tigervnc

I've been struggling to get Tiger VNC running on a Cento 7 instance, and have pretty much reached the same spot with any tutorial I've tried.

For instance I tried running through the following example:
https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/configure-vnc-server-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

After executing:

```
systemctl start vncserver@:4.service
```

I'm getting the following:

```
Job for vncserver@:4.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running the status, I get:

```
[root@centos-box gsa-admin]# systemctl status vncserver@:4.service
● vncserver@:4.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:4.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sat 2019-10-26 04:32:51 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 17389 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l gsa-admin -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1920x1080 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17383 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 26 04:32:48 centos-box systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Oct 26 04:32:51 centos-box systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /home/gsa-admin/.vnc/centos-box:4.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Oct 26 04:32:51 centos-box systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Oct 26 04:32:51 centos-box systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:4.service entered failed state.
Oct 26 04:32:51 centos-box systemd[1]: vncserver@:4.service failed.
```

I've pretty much followed the referenced tutorial step by step.. I'm not sure why the PID file for display 4 is not being created..? The only difference between the tutorial and what I ran is rather than using display 5, I chose 4.. thats it..

I've also tried deleting all the X1, X2, etc.. under the /tmp dir, but I keep coming back to the "Can't open PID file.." because it's not being created... :(

Any help would be awesome! thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the /tmp files were not removed if the server was not gracefully shut down.

Upon server start, tigervnc creates a number of files under `/tmp` and `/tmp/.X11-unix/`. If not gracefully shut down, these files could prevent tigervnc server from starting until they are removed -- and it fails with exactly the error message mentioned above.

Under `/tmp/.X11-unix` you might see files like:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 X0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 X1
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 X2
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 X3
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 X4
```

Under `/tmp/.XIM-unix`:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 /tmp/.X1-lock
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 /tmp/.X2-lock
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 /tmp/.X3-lock
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 31 18:30 /tmp/.X4-lock
```

To fix this, clear these temporary files:

```
rm -f /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
```

Then, try again to start the vncserver service:

```
systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
```

Finally, verify that the solution worked:

```
systemctl status vncserver@:1.service
```

Sources:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1410164

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/vncserver-service-failed-because-a-configured-resource-limit-was-exceeded